# Antlr4 Is there a way to walk on a node with a listener

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, regex-lookarounds

I am working with antlr4 to parse some inner language.
The way I do it is the standard way of creating a stream of tokens, then creating a parse tree with set tokens. And the last step is creating a tree.
Now that I have a tree I can use the `walk` command to walk over it.
The walk command and the parse tree being created are an extension of the **BaseListener** class.
For my project I use many lookaheads, I mostly use the visitors as a sort of look ahead.
A visitor function can be applied on a node from the parser tree. (Assuming you implement a visitor class)
I have tried creating a smaller listener class to act as my look ahead on a specific node. However, I'm not managing to figure out if this is even possible.
Or is there another / better / smarter way to create a look ahead?

To make the question seem shorter:
Can a listener class be used on a node in the antlr4 parser tree-like visitor can?

Comment: Sure, you can use a listener on a subtree. Just invoke it using the tree walker just like you invoked the main listener on the whole tree. I'm not sure I correctly understood your question though. Can you show an example of what your lookahead visitors do and how/why you're trying to replace them with listeners?

Comment: "Lookahead", typically refers to a parser recognizer needing to "look ahead" in the token stream to choose which parser rule to match.  Since you already have a Parse Tree, I must assume you mean "lookahead" in a different sense.  As @sepp2k mentions, an TreeWalker can walk *any* subtree, with your listener.  That's trivial, but your question is rather vague (what do YOU mean by "lookahead").  If you give a bit more detail, I'm sure we can help point you in the right direction (or clear up some misconception)

Comment: @MikeCargal First of all I appreciate the response. I will try to clarify. Look ahead in the standard parser means token recognition as you mentioned. If I have a rule with ```x+y+z``` and I would like to know the type of this expression. I will have to 'look ahead' in the tree walk and analysis them all separately (in C/C++ for example, if all variables are int the type will be int. if one is double then the expression as a whole will be double). Not sure how this is called. It's a semantic look ahead maybe?

Comment: @sepp2k Can you show me an example of invoking a listener from a visitor? I can't seem to find it and in my code it just doesn't compile. I would like to do something like this: 
```antlrcpp::Any ImageVisitor::visitShape(SceneParser::ShapeContext *ctx) {
  TreeLis listener;
   antlr4::tree::ParseTreeWalker::DEFAULT.walk(&listener, ctx);
  return Element::convertShape(ctx->getText());
 } ```
The code it self is more complicated but this is the idea

Comment: @Pichner If it doesn't compile, please post a [MCVE] including the error message you're getting. Anyway I agree with Mike that what you're doing seems too complicated for the problem you're trying to solve. Depending on the language, type checking can either be done using a single visitor or listener or, if the language allows you to refer to functions or types that haven't been defined yet, two consecutive ones (one to gather the definitions and the second one to do the actual type checking). Either way, there should be no need for nesting listeners and/or visitors.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no real reason to do anything fancy with a listener here.  To handle your example of resolving the type of an expression, this can be done in a couple of steps.  You’ll need a listener that builds a symbol table (presumably a scoped symbol table so that each scope in your parse tree has a symbol table and references to “parent” scopes it might search to resolve the data types of any variables.). Depending upon your needs, you can build these scoped symbol tables in your listener, pushing and popping them on a stack as you enter/exit scopes, or you may do this is a separate listener attaching a reference to scope nodes to your parse tree.  This symbol table will be required for type resolution, so if you can reference variables in your source prior to encountering the declaration, you’d need too pass your tree with a listener building and retaining the symbol table structure.

With the symbol table structure available to your listener for resolving expression types.  If you always use the `exit*` method overrides then all of the data types for any sub-expressions will have already been resolved.  With all of the sub-expression types, you can infer the type of the expression you’re about to “exit”.  Evaluating the type of child expressions should cover all of the “lookahead” you need to resolve an expression’s type.

There’s really nothing about this approach that rules out a visitor either, it would just be up to you to visit each child, determining it’s type, and then, at the end of the listener, resolve the expression type from the types of it’s children.